# Neostrada api, foreach the dns results

Tags: php, arrays, json, string, multidimensional-array

I don't understand how to foreach this response so it shows all the records instead of the full "result".

My result:

```
{"results":[{"id":83213964,"domainId":648668,"name":"pc-gear.nl","type":"SOA","content":"een.dnssrv.nl hostmaster@neostrada.nl 2019102501","ttl":3600,"prio":0},{"id":83213965,"domainId":648668,"name":"pc-gear.nl","type":"NS","content":"een.dnssrv.nl","ttl":3600,"prio":0},{"id":83213966,"domainId":648668,"name":"pc-gear.nl","type":"NS","content":"twee.dnssrv.nl","ttl":3600,"prio":0},{"id":83213968,"domainId":648668,"name":"pc-gear.nl","type":"A","content":"185.87.187.226","ttl":3600,"prio":0},{"id":83213969,"domainId":648668,"name":"localhost.pc-gear.nl","type":"A","content":"127.0.0.1","ttl":3600,"prio":0},{"id":83213970,"domainId":648668,"name":"*.pc-gear.nl","type":"A","content":"185.87.187.226","ttl":3600,"prio":0},{"id":83213971,"domainId":648668,"name":"www.pc-gear.nl","type":"A","content":"185.87.187.226","ttl":3600,"prio":0},{"id":83213972,"domainId":648668,"name":"mail.pc-gear.nl","type":"A","content":"185.87.187.226","ttl":3600,"prio":0},{"id":83213973,"domainId":648668,"name":"webmail.pc-gear.nl","type":"A","content":"185.87.187.226","ttl":3600,"prio":0},{"id":83213974,"domainId":648668,"name":"cpanel.pc-gear.nl","type":"A","content":"185.87.187.226","ttl":3600,"prio":0},{"id":83213975,"domainId":648668,"name":"pc-gear.nl","type":"AAAA","content":"2a00:f10:305:0:1c00:9fff:fe00:51a","ttl":3600,"prio":0},{"id":83213976,"domainId":648668,"name":"*.pc-gear.nl","type":"AAAA","content":"2a00:f10:305:0:1c00:9fff:fe00:51a","ttl":3600,"prio":0},{"id":83213977,"domainId":648668,"name":"www.pc-gear.nl","type":"AAAA","content":"2a00:f10:305:0:1c00:9fff:fe00:51a","ttl":3600,"prio":0},{"id":83213978,"domainId":648668,"name":"mail.pc-gear.nl","type":"AAAA","content":"2a00:f10:305:0:1c00:9fff:fe00:51a","ttl":3600,"prio":0},{"id":83213979,"domainId":648668,"name":"_dmarc.pc-gear.nl","type":"TXT","content":"v=DMARC1; p=none;","ttl":3600,"prio":0},{"id":83213980,"domainId":648668,"name":"pc-gear.nl","type":"MX","content":"mail.pc-gear.nl","ttl":3600,"prio":10},{"id":83213981,"domainId":648668,"name":"pc-gear.nl","type":"TXT","content":"v=spf1 a mx include:spf.totaalholding.nl ip4:185.87.187.226 -all","ttl":3600,"prio":0},{"id":92619388,"domainId":648668,"name":"pc-gear.nl","type":"NS","content":"drie.dnssrv.nl","ttl":3600,"prio":0}]}
```

My code:
Just the api and echo $reuslt.

If you have any questions, just ask. I don't know what to put here extra actually.

Comment: `foreach(json_decode($result,true) as $value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `$result` is a json string, you need to parse it to array with `json_decode`, then you can access it as a array. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/n82MW)

```
foreach(json_decode($result,true) as $value){
    print_r($value);
}
```

or access specific value

```
$data = json_decode($result,true);
echo $data['results'][0]['type'];
```

Comment: Thanks, and how can I now only show for example the type of the dns?

Comment: @Kevko check the Demo in my answer.

Comment: But I meant for every single like "result" show the type of the dns, not just 1 single.

Comment: `print_r(array_column($data['results'],'type'));` https://3v4l.org/djNK0

Comment: But is there a way how to put it in a foreach and it outputs just the answer and not the whole array?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_walk_recursive`

```
 $jarr = json_decode($result, true);
 array_walk_recursive($jarr['results'], function($v,$k){
  echo $k.'--'.$v;echo '<hr>';
 });
```

---

In table format

```
$data = json_decode($result,true);
$table = '<table>';
array_walk_recursive($data['results'], function($v,$k) use(&$table){
  $table .= "<tr><td>{$k}</td><td>{$v}</td><tr>";
 });
$table .= '</table>';

echo $table;
```

Comment: How to put it in a table?